# Why does c++(and most other languages) have both 'for' and 'while' loops?/What can you do with one type that you can't with the other?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Why do most programming languages have two or more types of loops with almost no difference? In c++, is one of the two better for specific tasks? What about `switches` and `if`'s; is there any difference there?

If not, then an answer about why they were implemented would be appreciated.

Comment: `while` allows for a more abbreviated syntax.

Comment: Syntax differences are obvious, I'm asking for functional differences.

Comment: `for` represents a common case of `while` loop,

Comment: There isn't a functional different.  In the end the loop gets compiled away into a label name and a goto.

Comment: The `for` loop is more strictly a `for-while` loop.

Comment: @NathanOliver `for(;;) {}` is shorter than `while(true) {}`

Comment: Language designers often add "syntactic sugar" features to make it easier/clearer for developers to write certain things

Comment: @Galik What do you mean by "common case"? Your answer implies ```while``` loops can do stuff ```for``` loops can't.

Comment: It is very common to initialize a variable, then loop WHILE that variable succeeds at a certain test, changing something on each loop.

Comment: @Galik What's a ```for-while``` loop?

Comment: It's a while loop with `for`sybtax.

Comment: But you can also do ```for``` loops without initializing a variable, right?

Comment: I think you just need to study the syntax of both and use what expresses the code best at the time. Originally people used assembly and everything was a while loop (or a do-while). When they created `C` they just tried to express what they had frequently done in assembler using higher level syntax. `while`is the general case, `for` is a very common variant.

Comment: @YoussefGamil Yes, just write `for(;;)` to have an infinite loop

Comment: **C++** has both because **C** has both, and C++ inherited them from C.  (C inherited them from B.  B from BCPL.  BCPL from CPL.)

Comment: @Eljay That just converts the question into: "Why does CPL have them?".

Comment: CPL has them because Christopher Strachey was a prolific genius (and perhaps insane).  CPL has a dozen-ish more loop constructs.  CPL is noteworthy that the project dragged on for a very long time, and ultimately was shelved never having produce a compiler.

Comment: @YoussefGamil: There's no guarantee that the level of expressiveness was preserved as the feature was "borrowed" from one language to another.  You may well find that in one of the predecessors, the `for` loop was restricted to a condition and update both working on the same variable, while in C and C++ they are separate expressions.  for-loops in some other languages definitely aren't as flexible as in C++.

Comment: A common mistake by those new to programming is to believe that code is instructions. It's not. Code describes program behaviour. The compiler takes the code, interprets the described behaviour, and then generates the optimal instructions that will provide the described behavior for a given target. As a result there are many ways to describe behavior because some of those ways will describe it better or more easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is *nothing* that you can do with one type that you can't do with the other, because mechanical transformations exist between them:

```
while (X) { body; }
```

can be written as

```
for (;X;) { body; }
```

and

```
for (A;B;C) { body; }
```

can be written as

```
{ A; while (B) { body; C; } }
```

The only difference is readability.  The for loop puts the update-expression `C` at the top of the loop, making it **easier to recognize certain patterns** like looping through a numeric range:

```
for( i = 0; i < limit; ++i )
```

or following a linked list

```
for( ; ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->next )
```

Comment: since the question is tagged C++ surely range-based for loops count as an example of a `for`-specific construct that offers a lot of semantic advantages over writing them "long form"

Comment: @HotelCalifornia: It's still just readability, range-based iterations have (and actually are defined in terms of) a mechanical transformation into the classic forms shown here.

Comment: And with an appropriate helper type, you can stuff the classic forms into a range-based iteration.